# Display columns in a table dynamically

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4 to display a set of columns dynamically. So, only at runtime I would know the number of columns and those need to be shown in a table.

This is how the code to show columns looks like -

```
<tr *ngFor="let result of results">            
                <td *ngFor="let col of searchResultColumnNames"  >
                  {{ result[col] }}
                </td>
</tr>
```

Now, I need to add a condition to it. If column name is a certain value like 'refId', then it should not be displayed.

So, I did as follows

```
<tr *ngFor="let result of results">            
                <td *ngFor="let col of searchResultColumnNames"  >
                   <div *ngIf='col !== refId'> {{ result[col] }}</div>
                </td>
</tr>
```

This does hide the column value, however, an empty td is created, which is not needed.

So, I tried putting *ngIf in the  (alongside *ngFor), but it seems that is not allowed.

How can I render the results dynamically, and also hide certain columns without creating empty td elements

Comment: you should probably filter `searchResultColumnNames` removing the ones you don't want before feeding it to the view. e.g. `filteredSearchResultColumnNames`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to wrap the inner `<td>` with `<ng-container>`

```
<tr *ngFor="let result of results">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of searchResultColumnNames">
     <td *ngIf="col !== refId" >
       {{ result[col] }}
     </td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using *ngFor, this HTML below creates a table from a 2d array which varies in columns and rows. I re-wrote this in Material, which is more tricky, but looks good.

https://github.com/eltimmo/angular-material-dynamic-table

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-tables

```
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let ratios of gearRatios">
        <td align="left" *ngFor="let ratio of ratios">{{ratio}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```